# The Fate of Shaarilla in "While the Gods Laugh"

Tags: elric-saga

"When the Gods Laugh" by Michael Moorcock was originally published in *Science Fantasy* number 49, October 1961.

Recently I read it as Book II in *The Weird of the White Wolf*, the third book in *The Elric Saga Part I* (1977, 1984).

The quest of Elric, Shaarilla, and Moonglum fails. Elric's companions drag him from the scene of his failure.  Later:

> They stood on the slopes of the high mountain and looked down in the green valleys below them.  The sun shone and the sky was clear and blue.  Behind them lay the gaping hole which led into the stronghold of the Lords of Entropy.

And I am not certain about the nature of the hole they came out of. What was its slope? Apparently Moonglum and Shaarilla had been able to get Elric out without too much trouble.

After a short discussion Elric and Moonglum leave in search of new adventures while Shaarilla remains behind.

> Behind them, standing stock still on the hillside, Shaarilla stared miserably after them until the were no  longer visible.  The jewel Moonglum had given her dropped from her fingers and fell, bouncing and bright, until it was lost amongst the heather.  Then she turned—and the dark mouth of the cavern yawned before her.

So obviously Shaarilla entered the dark mouth of the cavern.  But did she enter it by walking down a relatively gentle slope, or by flinging herself into a steep pit to die?

Answer (score 5):

I always inferred that she was throwing herself to her death.  She has made it fairly clear in the story that she feels there is nothing of value for her if she cannot complete the quest, and after finding that the book they were seeking is unreadable, she feels she has no reason to go on.  That kind of despair leading to suicide is a pretty standard motif.

However, in this particular case, there is an additional symbolism to Shaarilla plunging to her death.  The whole quest has been about finding a way for her to grow proper wings.  Her plight is her inability to fly.  So tossing herself off the edge effectively gives the gods one last chance to save her—by giving her the power of flight—before she dies.  It is obviously unstated whether any deities take pity on her, but perhaps Donblas does grant her wings just when she finally needs them.